is there an exception to rows explaining where the numbers are in the set of latin squares?
in the set of all latin squares, there's a characteristic where the elements of the nth row explain where the digit "n"s are.
for example, consider this 4x4 grid:
1324
2413
4132
3241
as you can see, the position of the 2s (from left to right, the 2nd row, the 4th row, the 1st row, and the 3rd row) coincide with the 2nd row (2413)
there are cases where this characteristic doesn't happen, for example this grid:
132
213
321
(the 1st row says there should be a 1 in the 3rd row 2nd column, but it's in the second row)
but if you rotate this grid 90 degrees clockwise, it has the characteristic again.
321
213
132
is there a grid that doesn't have this characteristic in ANY direction?

I'm guessing you could program this  up to size 5 by 5. The number of Latin squares gets very big very quickly  https://oeis.org/A002860 . Anyway, you need the program to check your "explaining" rule  for a matrix and the other seven rotations/reflections. So you need the program to take a matrix and produce its versions under the eight symmetries of a square. I suspect that most matrices fail your test as $n$ gets bigger, maybe not realistic to produce examples by hand.

Before I say the exception, (and yes, there is an exception) i feel like I should explain that explanation rule in a simpler way.
for each 1 dimensional listing, there are only cycles of 1 or 2
cycle of 1 is "there's a digit A in the Ath place, so it explains itself"
cycle of 2 is "there's a digit A in the Bth place and a digit B in the Ath place. they point to each other."
a cycle of 3 is the first thing that goes away from this. a digit A in the Bth place doesn't mean the digit B will be in the Ath place. in this case, there's a digit C there, and the digit B is in the Cth place, but this doesn't matter.
so you just have to bake cycles of 3 or higher into your Latin square.
just a column and row will do.
15423
5
2
3
4
(in this case, they're cycles of 4.)
and then you fill in the rest of the Latin square.
15423
53214
24351
31542
42135
for certification that this Latin square doesn't explain itself:
counting the rows from top to bottom: in column 1, the 2nd row says there should be a 2 in the 5th row. however, there is a 4 there.
counting the rows from bottom to top: in column 1, the 1st (bottom) row says there should be a 1 in the 4th row. however, there is a 5 there.
counting the columns from left to right: in row 1, the 2nd column says there should be a 2 in the 5th column. however, there is a 3 there.
counting the columns from right to left: in row 1, the 1st column (rightmost) says there should be a 1 in the 3rd column. however, there is a 4 there.
(despite there being 8 ways to rotate a square, it doesn't matter which way you flip the sides that aren't being numbered. in this case, it's always top to bottom and left to right.)
